# Trying to redirect all index.html on my wordpress site through my htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, rule

I'm trying to strip all `index.html` file & extension exactly like my `index.php` rule works.
Meaning that instead of

```
www.discretix/modules-hdcp/index.html
```

There should be

```
www.discretix/modules-hdcp/
```

It works for `index.php` but in `index.html` it Doesn't.
I'm using wordpress and my server is apache.

These are my htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~discretix/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~discretix/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you want to do an actual redirect? (The server sends a 301 http status code and a new location)

Answer (score 0):

The following rule will redirect the user from either index.html or index.php to the folder (this will be reflected in the clients browser address bar) using a 301 redirect (moved permanently), you might want to change this to 302 redirect (originally temporary redirect, but now commonly used to specify redirection for unspecified reason)

```
RewriteBase /~discretix/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html|php)$ ./ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks.
It works for index.php, but for index.html - it redirects to the root of the site...

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to work - It was a problem with my cache that prevented me from seeing the solution you suggested!